# Converting .qcow2 V Hard Disk into .VMDK (Windows/VMWare)

Tags: windows-7, linux, vmware-workstation, qemu

Is any way to convert a `.qcow2` into `.vmdk` on **Windows 7 64-bit** using **VMWare Workstation**?

i did that using a tool  `qemu-img` in my linux host (**SLES11**):

```
qemu-img convert -f qcow2 vdisk.qcow2 -O vmdk vdisk.vmdk
```

I've only a Windows 7 host accesible ATM and if it is not possible which tool should i use?.

Answer (score 3):

[There](https://cloudbase.it/qemu-img-windows/) is a build of `qemu` for Windows. Another note Windows handles arguments differently for some reason, so you would need to change your order to:

```
qemu-img convert -f qcow2 -O vmdk vdisk.qcow2 vdisk.vmdk
```

Comment: please read the question, before answer

Comment: That you can use the same tool, and giving the command feels like an answer to me

Answer (score 2):

Use the updated qemu binary to convert the qcow2 image to a vmdk image by running this qemu-img convert command:

```
qemu-img convert -f qcow2 -O vmdk -o subformat=streamOptimized source_qcow_image_path destination_path_to_vmdk
```

For example:

```
qemu-img convert -f qcow2 -O vmdk -o subformat=streamOptimized CentOS-7-x86_64-GenericCloud-1503.qcow2 CentOS-7-x86_64-GenericCloud-1503.vmdk
```

Update the vmdk version setting embedded in the converted image using this script:

```
printf '\x03' | dd conv=notrunc of=<vmdk file name> bs=1 seek=$((0x4))
```

For example:

```
printf '\x03' | dd conv=notrunc of=CentOS-7-x86_64-GenericCloud-1503.vmdk bs=1 seek=$((0x4))
```